# How to create Union Implementation data type with bitfields in Autosar?

Tags: autosar

I am exploring how to create complex data types in AUTOSAR. Been searching for the below concern, but I haven't found one that shows me the way with good clarity.

I would like to create an IRV in this form:

```
union {
    uint8 u8Value;
    struct {
        uint8 bit0 : 1;
        uint8 bit1 : 1;
        ...
    }stMyBits;
}unMyUnion;
```

Base on my own investigation, I found in SW Data Prop Ref what is called SwBitsRepresentation from where you can specify start position and number of bits. However, it did not work because the RTE generated code look like this:

```
union {
    uint8 u8Value;
    struct {
        uint8 bit0;
        uint8 bit1;
        ...
    }stMyBits;
}unMyUnion;
```

Compiling this will definitely NOT apply the desired bitfields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C bit fields are not supported in AUTOSAR for the lack of portability. If you want to implement a bitfield semantics you need to define an `ImplementationDataType` that aggregates a `SwDataDefProps` that in turn refers to a `CompuMethod` of category `BITFIELD_TEXTTABLE`.

Within the definition of the `CompuMethod` you can specify the bitfields and their semantics.

An RTE generator will honor this configuration by generating access macros that provide a more or less convenient way to access the bits in the host variable.

You can find more information about the definition of a `CompuMethod` of category `BITFIELD_TEXTTABLE` in the AUTOSAR document “TPS Software Component Template”.

Comment: Thank you for the directions! I will dig into this ASAP and get back here!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Uwe! This is exactly what I needed. The `ImplementationDataType` is at the C code level. From there, we can define several `CompuMethod`, in my case `BITFIELD_TEXTTABLE`, for a `AutosarDataType` of category `VALUE`. The `BITFIELD_TEXTTABLE` contains all necessary attributes such as mask, upper/lower limits and of course the meaning you want to indicate for each bit by using the `COMPU-CONST` attribute.